# pandas plotting group by dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I have this groupby dataframe ( I actually don't know how to call this type of table)

```
A            B                C
1            1            124284.312500
             2             64472.187500
             4             32048.910156
             8             16527.763672
             16             8841.874023
2            1             61971.035156
             2             31569.882812
             4             16000.071289
             8              7904.339844
             16             4046.967041
4            1             31769.435547
             2             15804.815430
             4              7917.609375
             8              4081.160400
             16             2034.404541
8            1             15738.752930
             2              7907.003418
             4              3972.494385
             8              1983.464478
             16             1032.913574
```

I want to plot the graph, which has A as x-axis, C as y-axis and B as different variables with legend.
In pandas document, I found the graph I try to have, but no luck yet.

[image]

==========edited ===============
This is original dataframe

```
    A   B        C
0   1   1   122747.722000
1   1   2   61839.731000
2   1   2   61839.762000
3   1   4   31736.405000
4   1   4   31736.559000
5   1   4   31787.312000
6   1   4   31787.833000
7   1   8   15872.596000
8   1   8   15865.406000
9   1   8   15891.001000
```

I have `df = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).C.mean()`

How can I plot the graph with stacked table?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the actual DataFrame? This looks like a multi-indexed dataframe but hard to tell. How did you get this from a GroupBy object?

Comment: @GalSivan Added original dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unstack`:

```
df.unstack().plot()
```